# Disabling payment module in Hookpayment function PRESTASHOP

Tags: php, module, smarty, prestashop, payment

I need to hide C.O.D. payment module when certain carrier (with ID 8) was selected. Ive decided to use hookpayment function to check for carrier ID and then return false if the IDs match. My hookpayment function looks like this

```
public function hookPayment($params)
    {
        if (!$this->active)
            return ;

        global $smarty;

        // Check if cart has product download
        if ($this->hasProductDownload($params['cart']))
            return false;

        if ($cart->id_carrier == 8)
            return false;

        $smarty->assign(array(
            'this_path' => $this->_path, //keep for retro compat
            'this_path_cod' => $this->_path,
            'this_path_ssl' => Tools::getShopDomainSsl(true, true).__PS_BASE_URI__.'modules/'.$this->name.'/'
        ));
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'payment.tpl');
    }
```

The problem is, that C.O.D. method is still there even if i select my carrier with ID 8. Can u please help me how to debug or find a solution ? Thanks

Comment: Maybe $cart->id_carrier is not equal to 8, but something else.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972366/prestashop-on-delivery-select-hide-show-payment-method/28982642#28982642

Comment: Please follow this SO accepted answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972366/prestashop-on-delivery-select-hide-show-payment-method/28982642#28982642

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $cart object does not exist, so $cart->id_carrier will never be equal to 8. You need to use (int)$params['cart'] instead of $cart.